# xslt variable behaviour in the case it is not defined?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT 1.0 and suppose one of my variable is defined like:

```
<xsl:variable name="not-ascending" select="//*[preceding::element-tag > text()]"/>
```

Case1:

```
<element-tag>1</element-tag>
<element-tag>3</element-tag>
<element-tag>2</element-tag>
```

In this case we can see the variable is assigned the `value=2`, that is whenever the order is not monotonically increasing, our variable will get defined.

My question is about the case where the order is monotonically increasing:

Case2:

```
<element-tag>1</element-tag>
<element-tag>2</element-tag>
<element-tag>3</element-tag>
```

The following question arises here?

1. The variable lifetime/behaviour?
2. Is it safe to define variable like this?

**UPDATE:**
I just have to catch the `non-ascending` case as an error, from suggestions in the comment, I think I can do something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="$not-ascending">
    <Error>element-tag must be monotonically increasing</Error>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: The result of an XPath selection can be an empty node-set. So whether your XPath in the `select` attribute selects some nodes or selects no nodes doesn't really change the use of `xsl:variable` in terms of "safety" or "lifetime" or "behaviour".

Comment: The "behavior" part may depend on how you're actually using the variable - of which you have told us nothing.

Comment: So, in conclusion the `xsl:variable` will be something like an empty string if `select` didn't match any node? It just don't feel very appropriate as we always have to make sure if variable has some matched node or not before using it?

Comment: An empty *node-set*, not an empty *string*. -- I cannot comment on what's "appropriate" without knowing what you're doing and for what purpose. You certainly *can* point a variable to a node that may or may not exist, then test its boolean value.

Comment: I don't see the problem, using the variable reference in e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="$not-ascending"/>` or e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="$not-ascending">..</xsl:for-each>` will just not process anything if the variable value is an empty node-set.  You might need to show us how you *use* the variable.

Comment: I got the basic idea. But the point I want to emphasis is that suppose I defined a _variable_ and later used it in many arithmetic operations, is it by default completely safe to do any kind of operations even if that variable turn out to be an _empty-node-set_ ? Or we have to say that the variable whose select-path didn't match any node has some restrictions, so there is always a chance that it could break your code?
_For example:_ Suppose we have to compare two node's value and one node is present and one is absent...

Comment: A variable that selects a node-set can be used in exactly the same way as a direct reference to the node-set. To take your example, the expression `some/node > 5` will always return the same value as `$node > 5` - i.e. `false()` when no such node exists - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUF